# xades4j Error: TimeStampDigestMismatchException: Verification failed for property 'SignatureTimeStamp'

Tags: java, bouncycastle, xades4j

I am trying to use xades4j library in a Java Web Service which verifies the XADES signature.

This web service works properly when the file and the timestamp uses the same digest algorithm, SHA-512. However, when the file uses SHA-512, and the timestamp uses SHA-1, I get the following exception:

```
xades4j.verification.TimeStampDigestMismatchException:
Verification failed for property 'SignatureTimeStamp': 
input digest and token message imprint mismatch
```

Here is the code from xades4j 
(`xades4j.providers.impl.DefaultTimeStampVerificationProvider:173`) which throws the exception:

```
if(!Arrays.equals(md.digest(tsDigestInput), tsTokenInfo.getMessageImprintDigest()))
{
   throw new TimeStampTokenDigestException();
}
```

Thanks in advance.